# how to refer another page element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a LocationInfo.jsp in which i am calling AddCities.jsp using AJAX

Now the Problem is when i am validating addCities.jsp fields like isEmpty and setting focus on  element if it is empty, javascript function searching the element on locationinfo.jsp and it is not setting focus on desired element.
I am new to javascript so plese help me.

here is my code:

```
function isEmptyField(obj)
{
if((obj.value==null)||(obj.value.length==0))
    {
    alert("Please Enter Value");
    document.getElementById(obj.id).focus();
    }
}
```

and textbox within the AddCities.jsp is like this:

```
<input class="combo" type="text" name="city" id="ctname" onBlur="isEmptyField(this);">

enter code here
```

Comment: are you getting any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: This code is working, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: if i run only AddCities then it is working fine. but when i am running   runnig Locationinfo.jsp it shows only "please enter value" but it is not focusing on required element

Answer (score 0):

2 comments
1. check that your "if" condition returns true?
2. if yes, try `this.focus()` instead of `document.getElementById(obj.id).focus();`

Comment: 2 comments, which you place in an answer?

Comment: it is not working. i think it is searching ctname field in Locationinfo.jsp rather than AddCities.jsp

Comment: Thank you for your support. Instead of this.focus() i used obj.focus() and it is working fine.....

Comment: I m sorry i actually meant obj.focus() i am silly sometimes. you passed this which is capured in obj... so yes obj.focus(). apologies! but great its working now.